# What precision can I expect from a double?

Tags: c++, precision

I'm coding a physical simulation describing a system having a critical behavior, it means that its properties in this regime have a really sharp dependence on the external parameters (water is liquid just below 100°C and gas just above for example). I'm not satisfied with my current result and I have now some doubts about the precision of my variables. I've been using doubles so far, but I'm not sure about the precision I can expect from them for example:

```
long double K = 0.274653072;
cout << K << endl;
```

and

```
float K = 0.274653072;
cout << K << endl;
```

give me the same output (0.274653), is it because of a parameter of the cout operator cutting after a certain number of digits or did I really lost everything after the 3 when storing it? If I wanted the best efficiency for a precision up to 10^{-8} or 10^{-9}, which variable should I use? (I'm using exponentials in my calculation if this matters)

Comment: Try checking in a debugger rather than using cout.  With std streams, the default double precision is 6, but that's just what's being displayed using the `<<` operator.  A double should have around 15 significant decimal digits of precision (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/03/07/float-precisionfrom-zero-to-100-digits-2/

Comment: Apart from visualization inaccuracies there may also be other problems like rounding and all those tricky things about floating point numbers... See [Goldberg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: To see the difference between those two values, try streaming `std::setprecision(20)` before each of them. By default, an output stream only formats up to 6 decimal places.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, IIRC, `setprecision` permanently modifies the stream, so there is no need to repeat it. This is also what makes it such a chore to use in most other circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter which variable you use. The difference is when you output that variable. Use `printf` for better precision. For example: `printf("%.3f\n", K)`. `%f` is used for float and `%lf` for double. `%.3f` from example above means the output is float with precision up to 3 digit.

Comment: -1 No reason to use printf in C++ when iostreams can get the job done [just as well](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Comment: At least it will output the right answer. Plus printf is faster than cout

Comment: If in your program pure float output using printf is significantly faster than using std::cout you might want to switch to a better compiler/standard library implementation.

Comment: @ComicSansMS perhaps you could type out the magic incantations necessary to make `cout` do the same thing? Also, downvoting a valid answer just because you prefer a different style is pretty harsh. IOstreams is a lousy library. stdio isn't necessarily better, but I really can't blame people for preferring the simple, easy-to-remember syntax of printf over cout

Comment: @ComicSansMS, `std::setprecision` is very troublesome to use and verbose. `cout` is very, very slow. Now, their use might still sometimes be justified, but flat out giving a -1 to an answer for not following your preference is just bad.

Comment: Fair enough, I admit that the downvote might have been inappropriate here. I will take it back and post an answer myself.

Comment: @ComicSansMS try to revert downvote once more. I have just edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've chosen the right tool? Scientific calculations in languages like C++ is a non-trivial art. If your calculations are so sensitive perhaps you should consider dedicated tools like Matlab, R or similar. Or at least use a specialized library for C/C++. Programming mathematical formulae in a series of calculations in a "naive" way may result in a significant accumulated error. There are whole books written on this subject.

Comment: Matlab, R, and similar might be preferable for other reasons, but they all share the same floating point precision issues.

Comment: @Davka thanks for the advice, although at this step of the simulation I really need to use a "compilated" program for efficiency, my simulations already take a few hours. I started in Python and had to change to C++ for this same reason. Using MATLAB would be a huge step back now.

Comment: @DonReba That's exactly my point, numerical computations are tricky to get right, especially when high precision/accuracy is required. Precision itself might not be the issue, although I'm quite sure that in specialized programs you can get higher (perhaps even unlimited) precision

Comment: @Liam than perhaps check for a dedicated C/C++ library. This may also improve the performance as you will be using highly optimized high-level functions

Answer (score 0):

The best article I've read on floating point precision is [this one](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/float.html). Its style happens to appeal to me. The canonical source on floating point variables however is "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic", which is reproduced [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) from the `iomanip` header to adjust the precision of the output by `std::cout`:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
[...]

long double K = 0.274653072;
std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10)
          << K << std::endl;
```

Note that in general floating point output is a difficult issue, so even on maximum precision the output might not be what you expected. The only way to get an exact output is by using [`std::hexfloat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and output in base 16 instead of base 10. This gets rid of any rounding errors, but of course leaves you with an output that is a lot harder to interpret for non-programmers.